# Jenkins is failed to checkout source from Subversion

Tags: java, maven, svn, jenkins

Hi All please do not put this question as a duplicate since I checked all the question for an answer before posting it.

My Question is this:

My Jenkins is hosted on a remote location and I don't have any control over it. I just can create a job configure it and run the build.

When I build the Job i am getting following exception

```
            ERROR: Failed to check out https://myrepo
            org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: Connection reset
            svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '/csvn/KBM/!svn/vcc/default'
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:106)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:90)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:764)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:371)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:359)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:710)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:334)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.runReport(DAVRepository.java:1303)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.update(DAVRepository.java:851)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.updateInternal(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:209)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.update(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:72)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.checkout(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:802)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:26)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:11)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgOperationRunner.run(SvnNgOperationRunner.java:20)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1259)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
                at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:115)
                at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:162)
                at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:170)
                at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:133)
                at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:162)
                at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:991)
                at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:972)
                at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:948)
                at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2688)
                at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
                at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
                at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
                at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
                at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
            Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
                at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
                at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
                at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:75)
                at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.XMLReader.read(XMLReader.java:39)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipChar(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:898)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:863)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:220)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:463)
                ... 33 more
            java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: E:\Myworkspacepath at hudson.remoting.Channel@1975e1ea:BuildSlave1: java.io.IOException: Failed to check out https://Myrepo
                at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:985)
                at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:967)
                at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:897)
                at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:833)
                at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:484)
                at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1274)
                at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
                at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
                at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:531)
                at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
                at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
                at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
                at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:381)
            Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to check out https://myrepo
                at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:126)
                at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:162)
                at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:170)
                at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:133)
                at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:162)
                at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:991)
                at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:972)
                at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:948)
                at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2688)
                at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
                at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
                at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
                at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
                at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
                at ......remote call to BuildSlave1(Native Method)
                at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
                at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:220)
                at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
                at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:978)
                ... 12 more
            Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: Connection reset
            svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '/csvn/KBM/!svn/vcc/default'
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:106)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:90)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:764)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:371)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:359)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:710)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:334)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.runReport(DAVRepository.java:1303)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.update(DAVRepository.java:851)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.updateInternal(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:209)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.update(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:72)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.checkout(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:802)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:26)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:11)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgOperationRunner.run(SvnNgOperationRunner.java:20)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1259)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
                at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:115)
                at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:162)
                at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:170)
                at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:133)
                at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:162)
                at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:991)
                at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:972)
                at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:948)
                at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2688)
                at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
                at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
                at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
                at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
                at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
            Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
                at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
                at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
                at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:75)
                at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.XMLReader.read(XMLReader.java:39)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipChar(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:898)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readData(HTTPConnection.java:863)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:220)
                at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:463)
                ... 33 more
            Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: ...and the question?

Comment: How to resolve above exception

Answer (score -2, accepted):

by mistake my team checked in .class files after removing the .class files from repository it is now working fine.

Answer (score -3):

Try the following:

1)Change your svn configuration to 'allow from all' on the httpd.config. So something like this if using apache 2.2

```
<Directory /repos>
...
allow from all 
...
</Directory>
```

---

Or if using apache 2.4

```
<Directory /repos>
...
allow from all 
...
</Directory>
```

2)Clean up the project i.e. SVN->Working Copy->Cleanup (if you are using netbeans)

3) Ensure you have enough disk space

Comment: I Using WAS 8.5.5 and SVN is also setup in remote location